# Django Model: drop a field

Tags: django, django-models

Is there a straightforward clean way to drop a field from Django model? for addition of a field, migrate works perfect but its not working for deletion throwing the following error

> django.db.utils.DatabaseError: (1060, "Duplicate column name 'xyz_json_old'")

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am using south but still I had to go through the following with the help of my friend -

He says I must have botched up something and some internal steps in south are not atomic

1. edit the models.py file and delete the column from the class
2. BASH PROMPT$ python manage.py schemamigration core --auto
3. MYSQL PROMPT> alter table core_tablename drop column xyz_json_old; commit;
4. BASH PROMPT$ python manage.py core

Comment: DANGER:  altering the database directly without doing through Django migrate will unsynchronize Django and the database schema.  In other words, you can lose the entire database as far as Django is concerned.  If 'schemamigration' gets around this problem let me know.

Comment: @Ron This was 9 years ago. I believe things have come far from there. I doubt if anyone will land up in this problem today

Comment: Please elaborate.  Are you saying that Django migrations can now detect and adjust to changes in the db schema made outside of Django?  While not 9 years ago, I almost lost a db this way.  That was 4 or 5 years ago.

Answer (score 12):

If you want to drop only the field from the model try this

```
$ python manage.py dbshell
```

You will get directly within your database shell (mysql or psql) it up to what database
    you are using.

```
$ mysql> | psql> ALTER TABLE <table_name> DROP column <COLUMN_NAME>;
```

Open the model too (the python file)and take off the field name from the model and type now

```
$ python manage.py syncdb
```

And it will drop the column to from table, doesn't matter if the table is already populated or not.

Comment: thanks. just noticed your comment after writing my set of steps.

Answer (score -1):

You can use [South](http://south.readthedocs.org/en/latest/tutorial/part1.html).

- Edit your `settings.py` and put `'south'` into `INSTALLED_APPS` (assuming you’ve installed it to the right place)
- Run `./manage.py syncdb` to load the South table into the database. Note that syncdb looks different now - South modifies it.
- Run `./manage.py convert_to_south myapp` -South will automatically make and pretend to apply your first migration.

Then edit your `models.py`, and then

```
./manage.py schemamigration --auto myapp
```

them migrate:

```
./manage.py migrate myapp
```

Comment: I suspect he's already using South, I think he's trying to migrate and that's where he's hitting the error. He may need to --fake a migration

Comment: This answer is very outdated.