# Django - sqlite - Delete attribute from model

Tags: python, django

I am a beginner in Django and up to now I was amazed how simple it was. I am running django 3 with an sqlite3 DB. I want to remove an attribute of one of my models. In this particular case it's "slug".

**models.py**

```
class Recipe(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    creator = models.CharField(max_length=42)
    content = models.TextField(null=True)
    creation_date = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now,
                                         verbose_name="Creation date")
    photo = models.ImageField(upload_to="photos/")
    main_ingredient = models.ManyToManyField('Ingredient', related_name='recipes')
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=100)

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = "recipe"
        ordering = ['creation_date']

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title
```

I just delete the line and ran

```
python manage.py makemigration
```

I got the following error

```
SystemCheckError: System check identified some issues:

ERRORS:
<class 'recipes.admin.RecipeAdmin'>: (admin.E027) The value of 'prepopulated_fields' refers to 'slug', which is not an attribute of 'recipes.Recipe'.
```

I suppose django does not want to delete the line from the DB. I have to do it manually then I tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20971792/django-model-drop-a-field)

But it does not work for sqlite as explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5938048/delete-column-from-sqlite-table/5987838)

So far I was amazed by Django and this is a major drawback. Is there an easier way? what am I doing wrong?

Thank you for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look in your `admin.py` file, you left a reference to it in there.

The error points to the problem. You deleted the slug field but left it in the `prepopulated_fields` of `RecipeAdmin`.